# Laravel update record with where condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-update

I have a table (Refunds) with a field named `"num_pre"`, I need to insert in all rows with `"num_pre"` equal to `NULL` a particular progressive code. For example first `"J0620222"` then `"J0620223"` etc, only when `num_pre` is `null`

I thought something like this

```
$data = Refunds::where('num_pre', '=', "")->update(array('num_pre' => ????));
```

but i cant because i need foreach to create the progressive code...
Thx

Answer (score 1):

First fetch all the records where `num_pre` is null:

```
$records = Refund::whereNull('num_pre')->get();
```

After that, loop through all the records and update that column:

```
foreach($records as $record){
   $record->num_pre = 'Your new progressive code';
   $records->save();
}
```

PS: Not sure how do you generate the progressive code, since you haven't mentioned it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Refund::where('num_pre', NULL)->update('field_of_progressive_code', $progressiveCode);
```

This translates to `UPDATE refunds SET field_of_progressive_code = '$progressiveCode' WHERE num_pre = NULL`

This will update all the rows that's progressive code is NULL with a given code.

Comment: yeah but code is progressive, if different for each rows

Comment: Do as @zlatan answered